# iOS Safari z-index bug on child element

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, safari, z-index

I've got a loading spinner for my AngularJS app that is beside a `<div>` containing additional items, along with an alert `<div>`. What I'm trying to do is have just the alert appear above the loading spinner, while keeping all the other content of the containing `<div>` behind the spinner.

I've created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKzJNw

This is only erroring on iOS Safari, all desktop browsers & Android devices display the alert on top of the loading spinner perfectly fine. I've searched and searched for an answer for this and have tried all the suggestions like:

- `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`
- `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);`
- `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

I had no success with any of the above suggestions.